# Basic frequency value, split by group

Tags: r, aggregate

I'm trying to get a `length(x)` value for a variable split by another variable.

```
aggregate(ssfia$Correlation_Abs,ssfia$Disorder,length,na.rm=TRUE)
```

However I get an error message:

```
>Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : 
  2 arguments passed to 'length' which requires 1
```

It appears that `length(x)` can't be used there like "mean" or "sd" can. Is there a function that can count rows nested in an aggregate?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no `na.rm` argument in `length`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about the following?

1. split the first vector into subclasses determined by the second one:

   ```
   cls <- split(ssfia$Correlation_Abs, ssfia$Disorder)
   ```
2. count how many non-`NA` observations fall into each subclass:

   ```
   sapply(cls, function(dat) sum(!is.na(dat)))
   ```

Comment: Fantastic, that worked! If you wouldn't mind explaining something--why does "sum" return a frequency count in this context but an actual sum in any other context? (I.e., I tried putting "sum" in the original aggregate function from earlier and it returned a sum.)

Comment: `!is.na(dat)` returns a logical vector. `sum()` accepts a numeric vector. Thus, the logical vector should be converted to a numeric one. The rule is: `TRUE == 1` and `FALSE == 0`. So `sum(!is.na(dat))` just counts how many `TRUE` elements are in the vector (e.g. we have `TRUE+TRUE+FALSE+TRUE==3`, as `1+1+0+1==3`).